# Django Rest Framework parser does not accept string as valid JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm sending some data to Django Rest Framework backend with Content-Type set as `application/json`.
If I try to send any JSON that is shaped like a typical nested key-value object, everything works fine.

But if I want to send a simple string like `test`, I get a `400 Bad request` due to malformed JSON : `JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

But aren't strings valid JSON values according to [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#page-5) ?

I don't understand from the [official DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) if this is a normal feature for Django JSON Parser or if I'm doing something wrong somewhere ?

The class-based view that I'm using is `ListCreateAPIView`:

```py
class ObjectList(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    View dedicated to GET a list of instances or POST a new one
    """    
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Filter objects based on user identity (token based)
        queryset = MyObject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        transect_data = request.data # Returns 400 Bad request
```

The piece of code that send data to the server (JS using Axios)

```js
…
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + 'create/', 
        "test",
        {
          headers: headers,
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: A simple string should be send between quotes, so `"test"`, not `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any [JSON *value* <sup>[json.org]</sup>](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so that includes a *string*, but a string is put between double quotes (`"…"`) and some characters should be *escaped*, so you send **`"test"`**, not <s>`test`</s>.

`test` itself is *not* a valid JSON value. Indeed, you can check for example with the [*Online JSON valiator* <sup>[jsonlint.com]</sup>](https://jsonlint.com/) if a JSON blob is valid JSON.

A string literal is, just like for example in Python and JavaScript thus put in an "envelope" of double quotes, and escapes certain characters such that if the string itself contains a double quote, that character is escaped properly.

Comment: Thx Willem, I've added in the question the piece of code in charge of sending data to the server (JS) just to be sure I do understand your point: you mean I should send `'\"test\"'` instead of just `"test"` ?

Comment: @Beinje: it will send `test` as "raw body", so you indeed should use `'"test"'`, or better `JSON.stringify('test')`.

Comment: Allright, I did not know about that, very useful, thx ! So the `Content-Type : application/json` is not enough to make the Django parser understand that the body should be interpreted as a string ? I'm not sure what could it be otherwise (what is the type of `test` if not a string) ?

Comment: @Beinje: the type is a string yes, but the *content* of the string is not a JSON blob. axios will only convert to a JSON blob if it is not a string, since then you can also post raw data.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for those details, this is definitely helping !